# Knockoutjs: Want to Fadein/FadeOut element when add/remove by knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

i am learning knockout js. so i am trying to learn from knockout tutorial site http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html. try to run their code in my end.

i just try to develop something that when i will add something in observable Array then a new will be added in page with fade in effect and when element will be removed from array then div will disappear from page with fadeout effect.
the code i tried is not working as expected. so my request to all please review my code and tell me where i made the mistake which causes the error.

### here is my full code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #dash
        {
            /*max-height: 128px;*/
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #dash div
        {
            border: 1px solid #de2345;
            padding: 4px;
            margin: 2px;
            line-height: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #dash div:before
        {
            content: '--> ';
        }
    </style>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <button id="button" data-bind="click: addRow" type="button">click</button>
    <div id="dash" data-bind="foreach: {data : rows, beforeRemove : ElementFadeOut, afterAdd:ElementFadeIn}">
        <div data-bind="text:$data">
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function TableModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.Counter = 1;
                self.rows = ko.observableArray([]),
                self.addRow = function () {
                    self.rows.push(self.Counter + ' ' + new Date());
                    self.Counter++;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        self.rows.shift();
                        self.Counter--;
                    }, self.rows().length * 1000);
                },

                self.ElementFadeOut = function (element, index, data) {
                    $(element).delay(1000).fadeOut();
                }

                self.ElementFadeIn = function (element, index, data) {
                    alert('pop');
                    $(element).delay(1000).fadeIn()
                }

            }
            ko.applyBindings(new TableModel());
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle link **http://jsfiddle.net/gLfmztqj/**

probably some mistake is there in code for which data is not removing from `setTimeout` function properly and also when adding element into array then also data is not adding after adding few data. what is wrong in this code. please check the code in jsfiddle and let me know. thanks

i just update the source code as per **@Rohith Nair** suggestion and now it is working.

Comment: #dash css is messing up with showing all items when you add. Firebug is showing  Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element. So I did put a delay on both fade in and fadeout and it seems working. $(element).delay(1000).fadeOut();  //$(element).delay(1000).fadeIn(); .

Comment: @RohithNair did you test them in Chrome? I tried your solution but couldn't get the `fadeIn()` method to work

Comment: if possible give a jsfiddle link of modified code. thanks

Comment: new jsfiddle link is here http://jsfiddle.net/gLfmztqj/60/

Comment: why this error message is throwing firefox `Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element` ?  any clue how to fix it?

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gLfmztqj/62/ for `fadeIn` effect

Comment: @Mou your guess will be good as mine about why that error is appearing, a quick search pointed me about putting the delay :). Thats why I didnt add it as an answer

Comment: @JAG thanks for your link. i do not see much difference in your code. so tell me what u change in the code ? why this error "Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element" is popping.....what is the reason. i check your link and getting the same error. thanks

Comment: `getComputedStyle` only takes `element` type node, you are getting this error because the `text` node got passed to `getComputedStyle`. just add a condition to check `nodeType` before animation. see the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gLfmztqj/69/

Comment: @JAG : what is the meaning of this line of code if (element.nodeType === 1) what is nodetype ? looking for clarification. thanks

Comment: @JAG i just use alert like this way to show nodetype value `alert(element.nodeType);` saw it is showing 1 and 3. what is the meaning of 1 and 3 ?

Comment: got the NodeType concept from this site http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp now it is clear to me. thanks

Comment: again got a link for element nodetype http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wanting to do this the other day so the html will look like this:

```
<div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: { data: list, afterAdd: animateAdd, beforeRemove: animateRemove }">
                                                // markup here
                                            </div>
```

The js functions will look like this:

```
self.animateAdd = function(element) {
                    if (element.nodeType === 1) {
                        var animation = 'Animation Type Here';                            $(element).addClass(animation).delay(1000).queue(function (next) {
                            $(element).removeClass(animation);
                            next();
                        });
                    }
                };

                self.animateRemove = function(element) {
                    if (element.nodeType === 1) {
                        var animation = 'Animation Type Here';                              $(element).addClass(animation).delay(500).queue(function (next) {
                            $(element).remove();
                            next();
                        });
                    }
                };
```

Comment: can u please post a full sample code with jsfiddle link to understand properly.

Comment: what is the meaning of this line of code `if (element.nodeType === 1)` what is nodetype ? looking for clarification. thanks